# How can an HTML button do anything without an onclick event handler?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out how these buttons are doing anything...

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I want to see the code that they execute to cancel and save but there are no event handlers, so I can't figure out where the code lives... is there some secret place it could be hiding? I'm really confused!

Comment: The code you posted alone won't do anything.

Comment: I know. I'm wondering if there's someplace the code that the buttons execute might be hiding, because I can't find any event handlers on the buttons. I was hoping that someone might know of some common trick to execute code on a button click without an event handler that I might be unaware of...

Comment: Not having an `onclick` does not mean there is no event-handler, it just implies that the event-handling is using an [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) technique, such as [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: The developer tools in Mozilla Firefox will show you attached events.. to figure out which handler is called

Comment: Which UI frameworks are being used here? knowing which frameworks are being used may help us point you to where these events are defined.

Comment: If they're doing anything it's because either themselves or a parent has an event listener. These can be added by `onclick` but are most often added by JavaScript through `addEventListener`. Honestly, imo, outside of React/Vue/Angular type scenarios, all HTML event attributes should be banned because they're objectively terrible in any sized project outside of demos.

Comment: I don't think we're using any sort of UI frameworks, but we are using jQuery..

Comment: Actually I do see some event handlers being added in jQuery-ui, so I guess we're using that... can't figure out what is actually going on because it's happening in the internals of a minified script, not in any code that anyone actually wrote for this app...

Comment: something noone mentioned is that `<button>` without `type` attribute is by default `type=submit` therefore there's no need to attach listeners in order, well, if that's your issue, submit a form.

Answer (score 2):

The developer probably used [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method instead of inline HTML handlers. When you do it this way, the event listener is added directly in the JavaScript (no need to mark-up the HTML at all).

Also, it's important to mention [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). If you implement this technique then each individual button would not need it's own handler - you can simply create one event handler function, apply it to a parent DOM element, and then inspect the `e.target` to access to the element from which the event began propagating.

Something like this, for example:

```js
const onClick = e => console.log(`You clicked ${e.target.textContent}`);
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```html
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
  <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
    </button>
  <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to reference JQuery's method of event attachment through `.on("click", ƒ)` or `.click(ƒ)` since the OP mentioned it specifically in his comments. @ekolis if you're using JQuery you'll want to tag this question and mention it within the question itself.

Comment: Hi ekolis - can you elaborate? You see what happening inside of jQuery? If you have additional code you could add to the question it might make it easier to find out specifically what's happening.

Comment: I see event handlers being defined inside of jQuery-ui.js.

Answer (score 0):

Aswer to title question:

Buttons actually can do some actions without using JS event handlers e.g. display some message

```css
.msg { display: none }

.cancelBtn:focus  + .msg{
    display: block;
}

.saveBtn:focus + .msg{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="cancelBtn" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
    </button>
    <div class="msg">You choose CANCEL!</div><br>
    <button type="button" class="saveBtn" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span>
    </button>
    <div class="msg">You choose SAVE!</div>    
</div>
```

Or submit form

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" id="form1">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a script, thought I'm not sure where it's actually coming from because it has a cryptic name "VM9850:formatted". Anyway, it contains this code which appears to be event handlers for the buttons:

```
 buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
        cdg();
    },
    Save: function() {
        // etc
    }
```

Comment: this is not an answer, might be an appendix to the question.